# Ubuntu not recognizing Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, bios, grub-legacy

I've got a Dell Inspiron i5559 which is about a year old. I have been trying to get Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 10, which I already have on my laptop. However, every time I try to install it, I never get the option to install Ubuntu along side Windows. I get a message stating that Ubuntu doesn't recognize another operating system.

I've tried installing it with both UEFI and Legacy settings, but no luck. I am trying to install it from a USB which I created using Rufus with the Fat 32 setting. I've also tried it with space partitioned and without space partitioned.

I know there is an operation for "Something Else", but I'm afraid to use it as I don't want to mess anything up. I've seen horror stories of people not being able to use their computer after given some bad advice. I want to be able to have the option to use either Ubuntu or Windows when starting my computer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a Linux novice, so laymen's terms would be very helpful :).

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use UEFI, but Dell is one that you may need UEFI in a mode that is both UEFI & CSM/Legacy. And must select UEFI boot of flash drive. Have you turned off Windows fast start up? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions And Windows updates will keep turning fast start up on, so make sure off.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Please see my answer to [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930816/trying-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-or-just-linux-in-general-having-prob)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to try those later when I get home. I had not disabled fastboot or hibernation, so that could be the problem right there.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.